# Using Bootstrap Studio and JQuery to dynamically add components to a page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-studio

I'm creating a form, mainly for mobile devices. I've done a fair amount of HTML/JS/JQuery/AJAX to knock up web app things but struggle to make things look pretty. I was toying with Bootstrap Studio for creating the initial page and components which I'd like to add dynamically to the page based on user interaction and REST API queries.

Is this a fair idea or am I going about it the wrong way? Let's say I have an app where I want to catalogue furniture in a property. I can create a header and a blank accordion. If the user hits an 'Add room' button, I want to add a 'room' card component as an entry in the accordion. Then, if a room's entry in the accordion is expanded, the user can then click an 'Add item' button which displays a modal form component which, in turn, adds an item card component to the room item..

Can I use BS to create a page and (separate?) components which javascript can then utilise? Would I need to create the components as hidden items in the page which I could then get javascript to replicate as necessary?

It's possible (even definite) that there are better frameworks for doing this like React or something. I was just wondering if this was a valid (or even sane) approach?